# How do I bind ftp client to a network interface

Tags: networking, web-interface, tftp

Sounds like as trivial thing but I can't get it done.
I've got the ftp client by `apt-get install ftp`.
Now I want to connect with some server but through specified network interface.

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous, are you trying to only connect through the Ethernet, but not the WiFi for example?  If so, there is an answered question here http://superuser.com/questions/241178/how-to-use-different-network-interfaces-for-different-processes

Comment: The server I want to connect to is reachable only through that particular interface, that's why I want to be able to choose to use it by the ftp client.

Comment: Each interface has it's own IP Address (Wireless could be 192.168.1.25, Wired 192.168.1.28, or totally different if they are on different networks), you should be able to connect to the IP of the interface that you need to use.

Comment: If it's on the network (as in in your subnet), it will automatically find its way.  If not -and- both of your interfaces have gateways defined, there's still a way to `route` the traffic for that very destination ip through a specific gateway.  This route won't be unique for ftp only though, but I cannot see why this would be an issue.